# iframe scaling on ipad: click area corrupted

Tags: ios, css, iframe, scaling

good day.

on ipad, scaling iframes using -webkit-transform: scale(2) corrupts iframe's clickable area:

click a link fails and shows the marked clicked area
in a different location from the link.

- only on ipad.  http://jsfiddle.net/adamhor/PCpuV/

.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html('<br><br>'+
    '<a href="javascript:alert(1)">link1</a><br>'+
    '<a href="javascript:alert(2)">link2</a>');

$("iframe").css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(2)',
        '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0'
    });
```

i saw this solution [CSS3 Transform scaling issue on IPad Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061942/css3-transform-scaling-issue-on-ipad-safari)

but i cant access iframe itself because of cross domain (i rather not get into)

thanks in advance!